# How can I open several links in a text file automatically without clicking each individually?

Tags: html

I have a text file with over 700 html links. How can I open all of them automatically without clicking each individually?

Comment: On what system? And how much memory do you have? :)

Comment: Thank you for this very interesting question, user1082234.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker is u means system i have P4 system and i have about 160 gb memory

Comment: @user1082234: Michael Krelin is asking on what *operating system* (Linux, Windows, FreeBSD)??? And 160Gb of RAM on a plain P4 seems improbable (perhaps you mean 160Gb of disk?)

Comment: @user1082234, Somehow I doubt you know your system well… That makes it safe to assume windows and that you want them in browser… I don't think your system will survive.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch windows XP and chrome or firefox

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i also have cor i5 system with windows 7 and 5oo gb hard

Comment: Congratulations! Did you consider installing Linux on it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand the exact meaning of *"opening a link"* for 700 of them.

However, there are libraries and command line tools able to be [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) clients. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is a library providing HTTP client ability to a program (and also to the `curl` command line program). And there is also (on Linux at least) the [GNU wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) package. The Qt library also gives [HTTP client ability](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/network-http.html). And many scripting language (Ruby, Python, Perl, Ocaml ...) can be HTTP clients.

Or do you want to open 700 tabs in a browser?

Comment: i have links like this  in text file  i want that every link open in a new tab or in a new windows and it close after 20 seconds, is it possible ?
(http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh) (http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh)  (http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh)
(http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh)

Comment: It is very probably possible for someone who is able to write some script or some code.